# weather icon not displaying in imageview in weather pp

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, icons, openweathermap

I am developing weather app with openweathermap api i have get and set all data and also getting image name in string but weather icon is not displaying in imageview.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class WeatherViewModel{
    
    var modelWeather2 = [MyWeatherData]()
    
    weak var vc: ViewController?
    
    func getWeather() {
        
        AF.request("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+(vc?.cityTextField.text)!+"&units=metric&appid=88236c7916643a06e2cd64d56f4e5077", method: .get).response{
            
            response in
            
//            debugPrint(response)
            if let data = response.data
            {
                do{
                    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyWeatherData.self, from: data)
                    self.modelWeather2.append(apiResponse)

                    debugPrint(apiResponse)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        self.vc?.tempLabel.text = String(apiResponse.main.temp)
                        self.vc?.titleLabel.text = apiResponse.weather[0].main
                        self.vc?.descriptionLabel.text = apiResponse.weather[0].description
                        let iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/\(apiResponse.weather[0].icon).png"
                        self.vc?.weatherImage.image = UIImage(named: iconUrl)
                    }
                }catch let error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

This is my code

Comment: UIImage(named:) is for images that are stored in your app's bundle.  It will not work with a url for a remote image.

Comment: how to set from url

Comment: There are many tutorials that you can find with a simple search. Here is one https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-load-a-remote-image-url-into-uiimageview

Comment: @AliAhmed if you print `iconUrl` what does it print?

Comment: I have solved error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as primitive solution as like the one posted below

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(for url: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            if let url = URL(string: url), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally you can use it as

```
self.vc?.weatherImage.downloadImage(for: "YOUR_URL_HERE")
```

Again, solution is highly primitive, doesnt provide caching capability or any other functionalities other than simply downloading the image

Comment: what is self. Image and what is = image both are same I am confused

Comment: its a extension to `UIImageView`, imageView has a property named image, hence `self.image`, = image is the image downloaded, if you see series of if let I wrote above, it has `let image = UIImage(data: data)` This is as simple as it gets in swift, if you are new to swift I would recommend you to read doc/swift manual

Comment: i am getting this error Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: 2 to things, 1. the code you posted does not result in error "Variable used within its own initial value "  2. Error has nothing to do with your question "weather icon not displaying in imageview in weather pp" If there is error, add the proper error, line number and all code associated with the error, the way you were setting image was also wrong hence I wrote code to download the image which was your original question after-all

Comment: Variable used within its own initial value this error is extension method which you provide not in my code

Comment: @ali-ahmed: There is no issue in extension, its compiling and working fine, issue is with your `weatherImage` I guess, you have a `weak var vc: ViewController?` not sure where you are initializing it, I guess your `weatherImage` is not initialized at all when you call `self.vc?.weatherImage.downloadImage(` again no issue I can see in extension unless you copied it wrong, cant debug further without adding proper details

Comment: @SandeepBhandari error is solved but icon is still not displaying

Comment: @ali-ahmed: May be downloading is failing, may be url is incorrect, icon is not displaying is very vague, you can try replacing `try? Data(contentsOf: url)` and replace it with `do try catch` and check the exception also you can try replacing `Data(contentsOf: url)` and instead use `downloadTask` of `URLSession` for much better understanding also to check if code is working or not instead of your url you can use any random image url and if that downloads obviously issue is with the URL you are using currently